# Can't edit a tag wiki

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I'm trying to edit the tag wiki of [rzslider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rzslider). After saving a popup shows - "An error occurred submitting the post." In the network tab, I see that the response of the request redirects to a 500 error page: https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/edit-tag-wiki/submit/126270.

Comment: It looks like a new feature got leaked as we now need to enter a Friendly name for documentation. The help text in the sidebar is also incomplete for that feature.

Comment: @rene That's unrelated. See my answer. :)

Comment: Do I get points for a good guess?

Comment: This issue is not resolved. I'm running into the exact same problem today while trying to suggest a tag wiki edit for the [tag:filesystemwatcher] tag.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The suggested edit queue was full at the time and we don't do a good job of showing anything that resembles a proper error message in that case.

Starting today (June 14, 2017), we're going to show more specific messages when the tag wiki edit can't be submitted due to permission issues, as well as when the review queue is full.

Comment: Do I dare read into this "but we will"? (usual caveat of 6-8)

Comment: @JonClements Sort of like "I'm on vacation this week so I hope someone else does it, but if not I'll see what I can do when I get back". :)

Comment: I'm honestly not 100% sure how difficult of a fix this is. If I recall, the edit submit pipeline is pretty gnarly.

Comment: What I'm hearing is that it's difficult to pinpoint which specific error is causing the "An error occurred submitting the post." message. OK, but then can this generic message be massaged into something less frustrating and unhelpful? For example, "The suggested edit queue may be full, or some other error is preventing your submission from being accepted at this time. We apologize for the inconvenience but ask that you try again in several minutes."

Comment: Also, I encounter this seemingly every time I try to submit a wiki edit. It's doing a very good job of discouraging me from attempting to contribute wiki material. Can we increase the size of the edit queue so that it is usually not full, rather than usually full? Or is it already at a daunting size, and anything bigger would just demoralize the reviewers? Also, are wiki edits in their own queue? If not, then that's a huge problem right there. If they do have their own queue, then it's tough for me to imagine it couldn't be made bigger.

Comment: @JohnY I am deploying better error messages as I type this. The size of the queue is a different story. All suggested edits land in the same queue at the moment. I've tried to make a case for raising the limit, but couldn't get folks to agree for various reasons. I'll ask someone from the community team to drop by with a more detailed explanation of the reasons/plans there.

Comment: The problem with raising the queue size is that we will simply end up with... a larger full queue. The issue isn't the size of the queue as much as it filling up faster than people are emptying it. Recent changes to the navigation mean the suggested edit queue is getting a lot less attention than it used to - we will be looking at fixing *that issue* (i.e. the cause, not the symptom), @JohnY

Comment: @Oded - I appreciate the response. I don't know how to turn the tide for suggested edits in general, but I do think that wiki submissions should have their own queue. Or they should be allowed to be force-added to the general queue even as suggested edits for questions and answers are blocked due to the queue being "full" (note the quotes). There should at least be some kind of special dispensation for brand-new wiki entries. When I am creating a new tag, I'm not so much "suggesting a wiki edit" as I am *creating* a wiki entry from nothing. Surely that ought to have different considerations.