# Unclear failure mode for tag wiki edit attempts when you have too many pending edits

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, quality-improvement

When you have low rep and are attempting to build reputation by submitting suggested edits, you see a rejection notice when you have too many pending edits (currently 5 on Stack Overflow, it seems):

[image: You have too many pending edits screenshot]

By contrast, when you attempt to propose a tag wiki edit, you are only shown a nondescript static tag wiki page.

This is vaguely documented, with a screen shot (so won't provide one here), but still a misfeature if not outright a bug; [Pending limit for wiki tag edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367745/pending-limit-for-wiki-tag-edits)

This is somewhat similar to, but apparently distinct from, [Can't edit a tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348865/cant-edit-a-tag-wiki)

Could we please have an actual error message with an explanation of why you can't edit the tag wiki in this situation?

Comment: I don't have links with me right now, but this has come up as a source of confusion on *many* occasions in the past, for many users. It's very strange behavior that's completely inconsistent with the way the same mechanism works in posts. It should be addressed/ fixed.